# Highcharts Is there a way to resize plotbands after zoom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, highcharts

I'm doing something like this to resize my plotband when the chart renders:

```
  var _Chart = new Highcharts.Chart( options, function ( chart ) {
     for ( var i = 0; i < chart.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands.length; i++ ) {
         var band = chart.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[i].svgElem, path = band.d.split(' ');

         var bottomString = chart.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[i].options.iMBottom + '';
         var topString = chart.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[i].options.iMTop + '';

         path[2] = bottomString;
         path[path.length - 1] = bottomString;

         path[5] = topString;
         path[7] = topString;

         band.attr('d', path);
      }
  });
```

That allows me to set the top and bottom of a chart's Y-Axis. We're displaying several Y-Axis in the same chart with some padding between them and each axis may have it's own plotbands. I don't want those to spill over into the other Axis since they look like smaller individual charts. I'm also changing the hover formatter to display a tooltip for these plotbands if a point within the band is hovered over.

The issue I'm having is that if you click, drag to zoom the plotbands revert back to the state where they bands go through the entire chart. I wrote some code to remove them and add them back in, but it seems like I'd need a callback on the addPlotBand function to change the SVG array before it's actually added and rendered. I've tried re-adding it then trying to redraw it, that didn't work.

Is there a way for me to adjust the SVG element when adding a new plotband so that I can alter the SVG element?

Edit:

Here's some more info. I tried using the selection event to delete all bands then call redraw, which calls a custom redraw event to put the SVG values back. Here's how that looks (the select event is first kinda crude but it works):

```
    SelectChart: function (chart) {

    var plotBandData = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < chart.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands.length; i++) {
        var band = chart.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[i].svgElem, path = band.d.split(' ');

        var plotBand = chart.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[i];
        //get all the plot band info so we can recreate them after resize

        var pbd = {
            from: plotBand.options.from,
            to: plotBand.options.to,
            id: plotBand.options.id,
            bottom: plotBand.options.iMBottom,
            top: plotBand.options.iMTop,
            color: plotBand.options.color
        };

        plotBandData.push(pbd);

    }

    //delete all existing plot bands:
    for (var i = 0; i < plotBandData.length; i++) {
        chart.xAxis[0].removePlotBand(plotBandData[i].id);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < plotBandData.length; i++) {
        //Add plotband back in
        chart.xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
            from: plotBandData[i].from,
            to: plotBandData[i].to,
            color: plotBandData[i].color,
            id: plotBandData[i].id,
            iMBottom: plotBandData[i].bottom,
            iMTop: plotBandData[i].top
        });
    }

},
```

Then my redraw event looks something like this:

```
    RedrawChart: function (chart){
    //SVG Code:
    for (var i = 0; i < chart.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands.length; i++) {
        var band = chart.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[i].svgElem, path = band.d.split(' ');
        var bottomString = chart.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[i].options.iMBottom + '';
        var topString = chart.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[i].options.iMTop + '';

        path[2] = bottomString;
        path[path.length - 1] = bottomString;

        /*JH: this is interesting, the second value for top is typically in the 8th spot in the array
            However, before it's rendered the two right most "L"s are removed shifting everything to the left.
            an example would be:

            After render:
            M 525 100 L 525 100 L 525 50 L 707 50 L 707 100

            Before render (which is the state it's in here):
            M 525 100 L 525 100 L 525 50 707 50 707 100

            So you can see that the 8th value after render which is second top is shifted over one space.
            The last value which is the second bottom is shifted over 2 spaces.
        */
        path[5] = topString;
        path[7] = topString;

        band.attr('d', path);
    }
},
```

My SVG values are correct at the end of redraw, however, the heights still get rendered to the full height of the chart.

**Edit:**

Now if I zoom in only the plotbands visible in the zoom stretch to the full height of the chart. Upon resetting zoom all all other plotbands are the correct size. Then if I select an area of the chart with no bands then click zoom out all the chart bands are correct. Seems to have something to do with only visible plotbands on select.

Comment: There is not callback like `afterAddPlotBand` - you need to use simple `redraw` or `selection` from chart.events and there remove - add - adjust your plotBand.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain that too well. Above is the code I use when I initialize my chart. I'm using the selection event to catch zoom, from there I'm looping through the existing plot bands and saving their data in an array. Then I remove each plotband and add a new one with the data I stored in the array. The issue is that if I add a plotband then try to adjust the SVG (using very similar code as above) the plotband has already been added and any changes to the SVG are not rendered.

Comment: But using `attr()` function change only SVG after element is rendered. I would rather guess that some calculations are wrong. Could you setup example on jsFiddle? With seeing this live I could find solution.

Comment: The fiddle is huge at this point. I found the answer though. I'll post it in a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked:

I created a new method that fires on the X-Axis afterSetExtremes() method (I suppose if you were doing this on the y-Axis you'd fire it there instead). I basically just took the code from the above two methods and stuck it all in there. Here's the code that fires off from the xAxis.afterSetExtremes() event:

```
    AfterChartSetExteremes: function (xAxis) {

    var plotBandData = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < xAxis.plotLinesAndBands.length; i++) {

        //get all the plot band info so we can recreate them after resize
        var plotBand = xAxis.plotLinesAndBands[i];

        var pbd = {
            from: plotBand.options.from,
            to: plotBand.options.to,
            id: plotBand.options.id,
            bottom: plotBand.options.iMBottom,
            top: plotBand.options.iMTop,
            color: plotBand.options.color
        };

        plotBandData.push(pbd);

    }

    //delete all existing plot bands:
    for (var x = 0; x < plotBandData.length; x++) {
        xAxis.removePlotBand(plotBandData[x].id);
    }

    for (var y = 0; y < plotBandData.length; y++) {
        //Add plotband back in
        xAxis.addPlotBand({
            from: plotBandData[y].from,
            to: plotBandData[y].to,
            color: plotBandData[y].color,
            id: plotBandData[y].id,
            iMBottom: plotBandData[y].bottom,
            iMTop: plotBandData[y].top
        });

    }

    $.each(xAxis.plotLinesAndBands, function (i, pband) {
        if (this.svgElem !== undefined) {
            var band = this.svgElem;
            path = band.d.split(' ');
            var bottomString = this.options.iMBottom + '';
            var topString = this.options.iMTop + '';

            path[2] = bottomString;
            path[path.length - 1] = bottomString;

            /*JH: this is interesting, the second value for top is typically in the 8th spot in the array
                However, before it's rendered the two right most "L"s are removed shifting everything to the left.
                an example would be:

                After render:
                M 525 100 L 525 100 L 525 50 L 707 50 L 707 100

                Before render (which is the state it's in here):
                M 525 100 L 525 100 L 525 50 707 50 707 100

                So you can see that the 8th value after render which is second top is shifted over one space.
                The last value which is the second bottom is shifted over 2 spaces.
            */
            path[5] = topString;
            path[7] = topString;

            this.svgElem.attr('d', path);
        }
    });

    //Need to reset formatter here?
}
```

The xAxis from the function is "this" from the afterSetExtremes event, so I just passed it through like this:

```
function() {return PureSense.Clifford.IM.Charting.AfterChartSetExteremes(this);}
```

that works. All the plotbands get resized after zooming in or resetting zoom. I actually walked all the way through the highcharts code with the methods in my initial post. I saw that the SVG values did get set correctly and held all the way through. Something happens outside of redraw though and I couldn't catch it.

I do know it happens though because if you look at my comments the "d" array is two items short of the SVG element on the page (if you view it with F12 dev tools). The afterSetExtreme event fires after redraw and after the zoom happens. I think writing those values during redraw causes them to get overwritten when the zoom finalizes.

Hope that's helpful to someone else.